# Why do I get FileNotFound in Python even though I have the file saved on my computer?

Tags: python, linear-regression, file-not-found

I need to plot some data with Python but I cannot get spyder to find the file with the data.

```
import numpy as np    
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import pandas as pd    
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression    

data = pd.read_csv('data(1).csv')    
X = data.iloc[:, 0].values.reshape(-1, 1) # values converts it into a numpy array    
Y = data.iloc[:, 1].values.reshape(-1, 1) # -1 means that calculate the dimension of rows, but have 1 column    
linear_regressor = LinearRegression()    
linear_regressor.fit(X, Y)    
Y_pred = linear_regressor.predict(X)           
plt.scatter(X, Y)    
plt.plot(X, Y_pred, color='red')    
plt.show()
```

It should show a linear regression but it just returns this: 
FileNotFoundError: File b'data(1).csv' does not exist

Comment: Is the csv located in the same folder as your script?

Comment: Try using the absolute path of the file and make sure that the filename matches the existing filename including, letters (e.g., capital), spaces, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think your interpreter is not running the script in the folder you're storing it in.

Try using an **absolute path** to reference your file.

e.g.
 
`data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\file.csv")` for Windows
`data = pd.read_csv("/home/{username}/data.csv")` for Linux

Comment: @TorinMay thank you! had forgotten about that. have a great day!